# Integrate $\int e^{\arctan(x^2)}e^x dx$

Tags: calculus, integration

$$\int e^{\arctan(x^2)}e^{x}\,dx$$

My friend asked me to do this problem. I am pretty sure that we have to use substitution at a point. I know we can rewrite this as.

$$\int e^{\arctan(x^2)+x}e\,dx$$we could say that $u=x^2$ and $du=2xdx$.

then i am pretty much lost from this point

Comment: Why do you think this has an elementary anti-derivative?

Comment: I am sorry I don't really understand what you are saying. If you are asking if this an basic integral. I dont think it is.  I just seen an answer posted a minute ago by some individual he used integration by parts. I am going to try using that method to solve this.

Comment: Your algebra in the integral in wrong and your differentiation is wrong. Did you find this problem somewhere or make it up? I don't think this has a nice solution. Mathematica doesn't know what to do with it either.

Comment: @Senal I overlooked something in my calculation; hence why I deleted it.  It turns out that if you do integration by parts, and then a substitution, the integral you're trying to find appears on both sides of your equation and cancels out.

Comment: So . This integral is unsolvable ? With conventional methods ?

Comment: No solution exists, probably.

Comment: One of my friends asked me if I can solve this. Our professor didnt assign us this question.

Comment: Oo. I thought it would have an solution. Because of $x^2$ has a derivative $2x$. I guess there isnt any solution to this problem. Thank very much .